# Traceroute return !x as MTU size

Tags: traceroute

I have 2 directly connected machine running centos 7, wanted to check MTU between them. So used traceroute tool to find it out.

```
Topology:
M23(10.1.1.20) <-------> M24(10.1.1.10)
```

**Expected behavior:**

Using --mtu flag in traceroute command should return MTU size.

**Actual Behavior:**

When used --mtu flag in traceroute command return !x symbol instead of MTU size(particularly when tried in M23 machine)

**Steps to Reproduce:**

```
[root@M23 ~]# traceroute 10.1.1.10 --mtu
traceroute to 10.1.1.10 (10.1.1.10), 30 hops max, 65000 byte packets
1 10.1.1.10 (10.1.1.10) 0.221 ms !X 0.166 ms !X 0.120 ms !X


[root@M24 ~]# traceroute 10.1.1.20 --mtu
traceroute to 10.1.1.20 (10.1.1.20), 30 hops max, 65000 byte packets
1 10.1.1.20 (10.1.1.20) 0.246 ms F=1500 0.226 ms 0.189 ms
```

**Version:**

**OS:** CentOS 7 on both machine. **traceroute:** 2.0.22

why is the !X symbol throws instead of MTU detail, how to fix the issue?

Thanks and Regards,

Mohan

Answer (score 1):

According to solaris traceroute manpage,

> !X
>
> communication administratively prohibited.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5166/traceroute-1m.html

It usually means that traceroute is blocked on the destination machine (M23 here). You should check your firewall configuration.